# Active Model Serializers: Configuration per serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

In the 0.10 branch of AMS, you can configure some options.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/configuration_options.md

Is it possible to configure those options on a per serializer basis? I'm migrating from a custom api to JSONAPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specified the adapter when you render json data in your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApiController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users, adapter: :json_api
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!